# How can I add array of object to html list by input form?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, pointers

I want to create dynamic lists in my page. Where user can add item to list from form. Something like this:

[w3school example](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_app5)

but I want add more inputs and send one object to angular function. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{food: "Milk", price: "1$"}, {food : "Bread", price: "1$"}, {food : "Cheese", price: "1$"}];
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        if (!$scope.addMe) {return;}
        if ($scope.products.indexOf($scope.addMe) == -1) {
            $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
        } else {
            $scope.errortext = "The item is already in your shopping list.";
        }
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function (x) {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        $scope.products.splice(x, 1);
    }
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-cloak ng-controller="myCtrl" class="w3-card-2 w3-margin" style="max-width:400px;">
  <header class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
    <h3>My Shopping List</h3>
  </header>

  <ul class="w3-ul">
    <li ng-repeat="x in products" class="w3-padding-16">{{x.food}} : {{x.price}}<span ng-click="removeItem($index)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="w3-right w3-margin-right">×</span></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="w3-container w3-light-grey w3-padding-16">
    <div class="w3-row w3-margin-top">
      <div class="w3-col s10">
        <input placeholder="Add shopping items here" ng-model="addMe.food" class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
        <input placeholder="Add shopping items here" ng-model="addMe.price" class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s2">
        <button ng-click="addItem()" class="w3-btn w3-padding w3-green">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="w3-padding-left w3-text-red">{{errortext}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

but if I added new item to my list and then I start change value in textbox so too change value in my list. There is something like pointer. If I send array of string then dont do it but I dont want connected to one string. Now I have connected to one string but I dont want it.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Create a copy using angular.copy() and then push that copied object to array

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what you want?  Like give an example of user-clicks-that which means that this happens, etc

Comment: If you will write something in textbox input and click to button then list will be increases of new item with text from textbox. I put here link for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a copy using angular.copy() and then push that copied object to array.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ngModelOptions to control how the model is updated:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

try this:

```
<input placeholder="Add shopping items here"
ng-model="addMe.price"
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
class="w3-input w3-border w3-padding">
```

Just mess around with what JavaScript event will trigger the update.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I try it but Now is not changed list when typing text box , but when I pressed button. I try look https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions .